# "Invoke-Sqlcmd | Out-File" not in matrix format?

Tags: sql, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I am using powershell to query a SQL table and then save the results in a file, this is working fine, however, the results are not stored in a matrix format but rather chunks.

How can I save the output like normal rows with separators tabs?

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "localhost" -Database "mydb" -InputFile "C:\Delivery.sql" | Out-File -filePath "C:\Delivery.txt
```

[image: powershell output]

Comment: Have you tried `Export-Csv` CmdLet?

Comment: Just tried it, awesome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the `Export-Csv` CmdLet to perform this action:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "localhost" -Database "mydb" -InputFile "C:\Delivery.sql" |
    Export-Csv -Path "C:\Delivery.txt
```